# How did the same user review this question for reopening twice?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

Observe in the [review history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history) (10k+ only, will get pushed down as more reviews occur) that a user reviewed the same question for reopening less than an hour apart (screenshot for posterity):

[image]

Looking at [the question's timeline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/200474/timeline), that user's first review completed the review task at 18:58, and the user performed a second reopen review of the question at 19:56. I am not seeing anything else in the question's history that would have pushed the question back into the review queue for that user.

It seems that the reopen vote count on the question went from 1 to 2 after the first review was completed with "Leave Closed x 3", but I did not think that would have put the post back into the queue, at least, not for the same reviewers (I did not receive the question for review again).

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm throwing a status review on this because I think there's something going on here which is either a bug or is at least undocumented. Hopefully that should send it to the appropriate team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the whole timeline. As you can see in [the post's revision history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/200474/revisions), the post was originally closed on Aug 4 at 14:07.

The post's 4th revision, on Aug 4 at 18:33, has the "added to review" note, which means that's what triggered it getting sent to the review queue — that was also a "significant edit."

As you noted, that user's first review completed the review task at 18:58. That's for [this review task](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/80351), and the result was "leave closed."

Looking at [the post's timeline](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/posts/200474/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries), I then see another user cast a reopen vote, on Aug 4 at 19:32. That vote sent it to the queue again. As you noted, that created [a second review task](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/80353), and that same user case a second "leave closed" vote, on Aug 4 at 19:56. This review task was completed on Aug 5 at 13:16.

Since "SAME USER" (as noted in the question) didn't cast any close votes, they were able to interact with both review tasks. [You note](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12161/how-did-the-same-user-review-this-question-for-reopening-twice#comment41969_12162) you were able to interact with the first task, but not the second: you were able to act on the first review task because it was sent to the queue as a "significant edit;" since the second one was due to a reopen vote and you'd already cast the original close vote, however, you weren't able to interact with the second review task.

So, even though the UI could be a bit clearer on why you weren't able to interact with that 2nd review task, everything is working as expected here.

Comment: So let me make sure I'm reading this right: a task created by a reopen vote is not offered to the close voters, but a task created by a significant edit is? Thanks for looking into this JNat!

Comment: That sounds right, yes, @ThomasMarkov ^_^

Answer (score 4):

### Repeatedly Leaving Closed is normal behaviour

There's two review items, because there was a new reopen vote after the first reopen review was completed. And, unless something was changed since the [new reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013) came in that I've missed, being able to act on each of them in normal behaviour (there are some restrictions on SO, but I don't think even those would apply here).

Whether the review item will actually show up for you can be a bit flimsy in my experience. In particular if you've already looked at it (you should still be able to go to it and act if you follow the direct link).

Comment: I followed the direct link to the review item, and it said I was not able to review it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That is strange. I don't know why you shouldn't be able to act on the non-closed one and KS was. It might have something to do with you having left a close vote, but that doesn't explain why you could act on the first one (and according to MSE shouldn't be a factor anyway)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Can you throw me a screenshot on the off chance there's any info in it?

Comment: [First review item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5613g.png) which I did review, [second review item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqv7n.png) which I can’t review.